# woocommerce reload cart page on applying or removing coupons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to disable ajax reloading only for coupons on cart page (woocommerce) when I add or remove coupons.
Need this to be with page refresh.
Is there any instructions for achieving it?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the ajax complete of apply coupons and reload the page.

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === '/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon' || settings.url === '/?wc-ajax=remove_coupon') {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

It's not perfect but it will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you!
I added on action("wp_footer") and worked.
Need only help to disable ajax only for coupons and i am ready.